# Exceptions using CruiseControl.NET

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I recently updated to CC.NET 1.5 and I'm now getting some strange exceptions.

On one project I get: -
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: svn: Can't create a character converter from native encoding to 'UTF-8'

This happens when CC is checking a subversion repository for any mods. If I run the actual command line CC says is failing it works and returns an empty XML (there are no mods).

Some other projects also fail to check mods with another "Source control operation failed" exception but no further info. Again the command is an "svn log" which when run from command line works ok.

I'm using subversion 1.4.5 client side and my source repository exists on a separate box than my build server.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: We are now moving to use Jenkins which seems to play nicer with subversion. Thanks to all that offered answers.

Answer (score 2):

1. Have u try to update Svn client ? I doubt it is so simple, but let's check !
2. Try a svn cleanup
3. What is your svn config in ccnet ?
4. What is the build revision of ccnet you are using ? You should try the latest 1.5.x nigthly build, which is very stable for me.
   http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/CCNet-builds/1.5.0/

Comment: Just got back onto this...

Tried a later ccnet revision - 1.5.6804.1 but still failing.
I updated the repository to 1.6.6 and binned off the working copy and refreshed using svn 1.6.6 client but still failing.

I'm now considering going back to the version of ccnet I was using originally. :(

Comment: hey, as I said before, try a more recent build of CCNET 1.5x
Latest is 1.5.7233.1.
Link is tha same as my post : http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/CCNet-builds/1.5.0/

Answer (score 1):

did you try to change the startup parameters of CCService?

Namely, set the "Allow service to interact with desktop" check box on Log On tab.
Also, you may try to use other account than "Local System".

I am not sure, but seems it may fix the issue, since it may be "Local System" account specific issue effect.